# VL6180X returning to its default i2c address after shutdown

Tags: i2c

According to [this thread](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?t=123872) the VL6180X after changing the i2c address the new address should persist after a power down. but when i changed mine it came back to its default address at 0x29. Here is the code i used to change the address

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_VL6180X.h"

Adafruit_VL6180X vl = Adafruit_VL6180X();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // wait for serial port to open on native usb devices
  while (!Serial) {
    delay(1);
  }

  Wire.setSDA(0);
  Wire.setSCL(1);
  Wire.begin();

  Serial.println("Adafruit VL6180x test!");
  if (! vl.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to find sensor");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Sensor found!");
  vl.setAddress(0x35);
}
```

After running this code i then ran a i2c scanner code which indeed showed the new 0x35 address but when i re-plugged the power it went back to 0x29. Am i doing something wrong here? Or the thread is just wrong ?

Comment: The data sheet and the thread agree with what you are seeing...the device will always power up at the default address, but you can change the address *while* it is powered up.  The Pololu link is explicit about this: "It can be changed to any other value by writing one of the device configuration registers, but the new address only applies until the sensor is reset or powered off." I don't see anything in the thread that says that you can change the default value when first powered up.